# Create random ints with minimum and maximum from Random.NextBytes()

Tags: c#, random

Title pretty much says it all. I know I could use `Random.NextInt()`, of course, but I want to know if there's a way to turn unbounded random data into bounded without statistical bias. (This means no `RandomInt() % (maximum-minimum)) + minimum`). Surely there is a method like it, that doesn't introduce bias into the data it outputs?

Comment: Scaling the value from `Random.NextDouble` seems like a good choice. Though it gives values from 0.0 up to but not including 1.0, so that might be an issue.

Comment: The ONLY perfectly unbiased method is rejection sampling. That is, generate enough random bits to cover your range, and if the value is outside the range, reject it and generate another until you get one inside the range. This can be more or less efficient depending on how close your range is to a power of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that the bits are randomly distributed, I would suggest:

- Generate enough bytes to get a number within the range (e.g. 1 byte to get a number in the range 0-100, 2 bytes to get a number in the range 0-30000 etc).
- Use only enough bits from those bytes to cover the range you need. So for example, if you're generating numbers in the range 0-100, take the bottom 7 bits of the byte you've generated
- Interpret the bits you've got as a number in the range [0, 2<sup>n</sup>) where `n` is the number of bit
- Check whether the number is in your desired range. It should be at least half the time (on average)
- If so, use it. If not, repeat the above steps until a number *is* in the right range.

The use of just the required number of bits is key to making this efficient - you'll throw away up to half the number of bytes you generate, but no more than that, assuming a good distribution. (And if you are generating numbers in a nicely binary range, you won't need to throw anything away.)

Implementation left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Too tired to do the math, but if you use slightly more bits and a mod operator - only throwing the last range away - you might be more efficient.  Check out `IsFullSet` in http://pastebin.com/DBxc9020 - albiet in this implementation I'm not trying to save any bits at all.

Comment: @NPSF3000: Possibly. I'm generally happier with "simple and obviously right" which is what I'm aiming for with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with something like:

```
public static int MyNextInt(Random rnd, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    var buffer = new byte[4];
    rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
    uint num = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);

    // The +1 is to exclude the maxValue in the case that 
    // minValue == int.MinValue, maxValue == int.MaxValue
    double dbl = num * 1.0 / ((long)uint.MaxValue + 1);

    long range = (long)maxValue - minValue;
    int result = (int)(dbl * range) + minValue;
    return result;
}
```

Totally untested... I can't guarantee that the results are truly pseudo-random... But the idea of creating a `double` (`dbl`) number is the same used by the `Random` class. Only I use the `uint.MaxValue` as the base instead of `int.MaxValue`. In this way I don't have to check for negative values of the `buffer`.

Comment: Well, yes, I know. I'm asking to do it specifically without using that, only Random.NextBytes()

Comment: @AlphaMCubed Ok... I hadn't noticed the title of the question... Changed to a code that uses `Random.NextBytes()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is biased in all kinds of ways but I can't say how.

Comment: @usr With ranges up to 100000 it seems to be able to generate all the possible numbers with nearly equal probability... The idea of using the `double` is from Microsoft... As I've written, they use a `int.MaxValue` instead of a `uint.MaxValue`, but I hope that the extra bit (the sign) won't change anything in the `double` division. But I do concur that the first time I saw it I thought "they are fools... `double` numbers will wreck something somewhere... their density isn't constant..."

Comment: With ranges up to 100000 the simple integer method also generates everything with roughly equal probability. I'm just extremely unconfident in this particular method. The double method is from the Random class, I know that. I think it's acceptable in practice but not exactly what was asked... (Also the random number support in the BCL is shamefully bad. All common issues that people have with it are fixable, even seeding.)

Answer (score 1):

I propose a generator of random integers, based on NextBytes.
This method discards only 9.62% of bits in average over the word size range for positive Int32's due to the usage of Int64 as a representation for bit manupulation.

Maximum bit loss occurs at word size of 22 bits, and it's 20 lost bits of 64 used in byte range conversion. In this case bit efficiency is 68.75%

Also, 25% of values are lost because of clipping the unbound range to maximum value.

Be careful to use Take(N) on the IEnumerable returned, because it's an infinite generator otherwise.

I'm using a buffer of 512 long values, so it generates 4096 random bytes at once. If you just need a sequence of few integers, change the buffer size from 512 to a more optimal value, down to 1.

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetRandomIntegers(this Random r, int max)
    {
        if (max < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("max", max, "Must be a positive value.");

        const int longWordsTotal = 512;
        const int bufferSize = longWordsTotal * 8;
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        var wordSize = (int)Math.Log(max, 2) + 1;

        while(true)
        {
            r.NextBytes(buffer);
            for (var longWordIndex = 0; longWordIndex < longWordsTotal; longWordIndex++)
            {
                ulong longWord = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, longWordIndex);
                var lastStartBit = 64 -  wordSize;
                var count = 0;
                for (var startBit = 0; startBit <= lastStartBit; startBit += wordSize)
                {
                    count ++;                       
                    var mask = ((1UL << wordSize) - 1) << startBit;                 
                    var unboundValue = (int)((mask & longWord) >> startBit);
                    if (unboundValue <= max)
                        yield return unboundValue;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: updated the answer with more occurate efficiency estimation.